# Node js -TypeError: Cannot read property

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, postman

I am working on a test signup with nodejs, i set up a free mongo lab database and testing signups on my local server. i keep getting this error an on my route, i can console upto var user = new User(); (console- user) and get the objects . I can console user.profile and console will display name and picture as objects etc. but for some reason my code is saying user.profile.name is undefined . Any error you guys can spot ?

[image]

**this is my model**

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UsersSchema = new Schema({

    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        lowercase: true
    },
    password: String,

    profile: {
        name: { type: String, default: '' },
        picture: { type: String, default: '' }
    },

    address: String,
    history: [{
        date: Date,
        paid: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    }]

});

UsersSchema.pre('save',function(next){
    var user = this;
    if(!user.isModified('password')) return next();

    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt){
        if(err) return next(err);

        bcrypt.hash(user.password,salt, null,function(err,hash){
            if (err) return next(err);
            user.password = hash;
            next();
        });
     
    })
})

UsersSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(password){
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password)
}

module.exports = mongoose.model('User',UsersSchema);
```

**this my route file**

```js
var router = require('express').Router();
var User = require('../models/users');

// var user  = new User();
// console.log('user',user.profile.name);
router.post('/signup', function(req, res, next) {
    var user = new User();
  
    user.profile.name = req.body.name;
    user.email = req.body.email;
    user.password = req.body.password;
  
    User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, function(err, existingUser) {
  
      if (existingUser) {
        return res.redirect('/signup');
      } else {
        user.save(function(err, user) {
          if (err) return next(err);
          res.json("New user has been created");
    
        });
      }
    });
  });


module.exports = router;

//res.json("New user has been created")
```

Comment: you are assigning `user.profile.name = req.body.name;` in this statement without an profile property defined. put this one line above: `user.profile = {}`

Comment: @guijob   but isn't it already defined in the model? . i did a "console.log('user object, 'user)"  right under var user = new User and got - user object { profile: { name: '', picture: '' }, .  i did as you said and still threw the same error

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to assign profile to something first as user is defined but user.profile is not
defined `user.profile = ''` before the line  `user.profile.name = req.body.name`

or replace the following and try

`-var User = require('../models/users');` with `var UsersSchema = require('../models/users');`

-`var user = new User();` with `var user = new UsersSchema();`

Comment: but isnt user an object that contains profile? isn't it already defined in the model? . i did a "console.log('user object, 'user)"  right under var user = new User and got - user object { profile: { name: '', picture: '' }, .  i did as you said and still threw the same error

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access `name` property from `profile`, which is not defined.

```
var user = new User();
user.profile.name = req.body.name;
-----------/\
```

To make this work, first define `profile`:

```
var user = new User();
user.profile = {};
user.profile.name = req.body.name;
```

Comment: but isn't it already defined in the model? . i did a "console.log('user object, 'user)"  right under var user = new User and got - user object { profile: { name: '', picture: '' }, .  i did as you said and still threw the same error